# VSCode Extension clangd does not correctly find all headers and links of embedded project using remote workspace with cmakelists

Tags: visual-studio-code, clangd

I just had to conquer the question on why VSCode Extension clangd does not correctly find all headers and links within an embedded project while being connected to a remote workspace, so i figured someone else might find this immensely useful on how this worked. I'm not asking a question but rather giving you the answer, in case someone else is struggling with this problem. Some other threads on stackoverflow helped me figure this out, but i guess its useful to have it all in one place as one big recipe.

I am developing a *cmakelists.txt* project using an *aarch64-linux-gnu-g++* compiler.
In order for the clangd extension to find the projects headers, the *compilation_database.json* is needed to be made known to clangd, so inside *cmakelists.txt* insert this code to generate the *compilation_database.json*:

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
if(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})
endif()
```

this will generate the *compilation_database.json* and also include the implicit include directories into the *compilation_database.json*.
As the *compilation_database.json* has the link to the compiler, which in my case was in a fixed place somewhere at */compiler/elbe_sdk_x.x.x/sysroots/host/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++* where i did not have any rights to the folder */compiler* to add the newest version of *elbe_sdk_x.x.x*, i had to adjust the *compilation_database.json* for my local version of the compiler */home/user/elbe_sdk/sysroots/host/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++* therefore i copied the *compilation_database.json* to */home/user/project/compilation_database.json* and replaced all occurences of the fixed compiler path inside the database from */compiler/elbe_sdk_x.x.x/sysroots/host/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++* to my local compiler path */home/user/elbe_sdk/sysroots/host/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++* ( - Note here: this has to be done, everytime the *compiler_database.json* changes due to changes of the project, then delete */home/user/.config/clangd* folder and restart VSCode so that clangd re-indexes all the links and headers)

Now continue with clangd configuration: change your VSCode clangd extensions *settings.json* to

```
    \"clangd.arguments\": [\"-log=verbose\", 
                        \"-pretty\",
                        \"--background-index\",
                        \"--query-driver=/home/user/elbe_sdk/sysroots/host/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++\",
                        \"--compile-commands-dir=/home/user/project/\",
                        \"--all-scopes-completion\"]
```

as the compiler that i use had a fixed *rpath* and *interpreterpath* in elf

```
readelf -a /home/user/elbe_sdk/sysroots/host/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++
>>>
[...]
Requesting program interpreter: /compiler/elbe_sdk_x.x.x/sysroots/host/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
[...]
Library runpath: [/compiler/elbe_sdk_x.x.x/sysroots/host/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/compiler/elbe_sdk_x.x.x/sysroots/host/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/compiler/elbe_sdk_x.x.x/sysroots/host/usr/lib:/compiler/elbe_sdk_x.x.x/sysroots/host/lib]
[...]
```

and therefore could not be invoked by clangd's query-driver function, i used

```
    patchelf --set-rpath /home/user/elbe_sdk/sysroots/host/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/home/user/elbe_sdk/sysroots/host/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/home/user/elbe_sdk/sysroots/host/usr/lib:/home/user/elbe_sdk/sysroots/host/lib aarch64-linux-gnu-g++
    patchelf --set-interpreter /home/user/elbe_sdk/sysroots/host/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 aarch64-linux-gnu-g++
```

to change the rpath and interpreterpath to correspond with my local version of the compiler.
Now clangd already found some includes, headers and references, but dropped out of correctly indexing due to *"fatal_too_many_errors"*, which can be changed by adding

```
CompileFlags:
  Add: -ferror-limit=0
```

to */home/user/.config/clangd/config.yaml* (in case the folder */home/user/.config/clangd* does not exist, create it and create *config.yaml* inside, with the set *ferror-limit* value inside, where *0* means *"no limitation"*)

Last but not least restart VSCode and let it re-index all the files (in case it already indexed, delete the folder */home/user/.config/clangd* as mentioned above before restarting). Your includes and references should now all be resolved correctly :)

Comment: shouldn't the file be named "compile_commands.json"?

Answer (score 0):

The find/replace step can probably be omitted if you instead override the compiler using [clangd's config file](https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html#compiler) like so:

```yaml
CompileFlags:
  Compiler: /home/user/elbe_sdk/sysroots/host/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++
```